# How do these 2 functions differ in terms of security?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security, attacks

How are these 2 functions different in terms of security, there was a question on a forum and i don't understand

```
function emergencyWithdraw(uint256 _pid) public {
    PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
    UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][msg.sender];
    pool.token.safeTransfer(address(msg.sender), user.amount);
    emit EmergencyWithdraw(msg.sender, _pid, user.amount);
    user.amount = 0;
    user.rewardDebt = 0;
}

function emergencyWithdraw(uint256 _pid) public {
    PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
    UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][msg.sender];
    user.amount = 0;
    user.rewardDebt = 0;
    pool.token.safeTransfer(address(msg.sender), user.amount);
    emit EmergencyWithdraw(msg.sender, _pid, user.amount);
    
}
```

NOTE: I'm new to solidity

Answer (score 1):

So lets imagine that the `pool.token` contract in the first function is somehow compromised and now the `pool.token.safeTransfer()` function is not only transferring the token but also calling again the `emergencyWithdraw()`. When the function is entered for second time the `user.amount` will not be `0` and the user will get `2*user.amount` instead of once and this will continue untill all tokens are transferred or until the gas is depleted.
However the second function is setting `user.amount = 0` and even if the contract is compromised every entrance after the first will transfer `0` tokens to the `msg.sender` which is okay.

This is called **Reentrancy** attack. [Here](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/09smart-contracts-security.asciidoc) you can check further explanations.